# from django.db import models is broken in a django standalone crontab script

Tags: python, django, django-models, cron

Before posting this, i'ved tried a wide variety of possibilities for getting this custom script to work (with no success). I have a script in a /lib directory which is being run in the crontab every X minutes.

The first few lines of this script are:

```
# /project/lib/script.py

import os
import sys
def setup_environment():
    pathname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.path.insert(0, pathname)
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pathname, '..')))
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings")

setup_environment() 
from Model.models import Model # This works perfectly fine
```

The traceback for the exception does not occur in that file but in the Model.py.

```
#/project/Model/models.py

import os
print os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] # Prints out Project.settings as expec
from django.db import models # ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the trace error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "/home/username/webapps/folder/Project/scripts/standalone.py", line 29, in 
   <module> from Model.models import Model File "/home/username/webapps/folder/
   Project/App/models.py", line 15, in <module> from django.db import models
   ImportError: No module named django.db
```

This code works when run from the command line, but fails in crontab.

Something that may be notable. The above ^ process used to work 100%, but after I added a few more scripts to the equation things began to break. I removed everything I had added .. however now it won't load anything django related!! It's not just db.models, any django related code I try to input in models.py is rejected.

Thank you.

Comment: where is the full trace error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/webapps/folder/Project/scripts/standalone.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Model.models import Model
  File "/home/username/webapps/folder/Project/App/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named django.db

Comment: ill post this in the question so it's better formatted, sec

Comment: made a mistake on the trace, check again

Comment: import pb are often due to python path. as far as i know, Python looks for the first "django" module in the PYTHONPATH and tries to find a db module.

Have you tried using ipython for running the line "from django.db import models" ? What do he says?

Comment: Did you tried to use [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales)? It allows to run your python code (with Django project context) via manage.py script. And, of course, you can add this command to your crontab: `python /path/to/project/manage.py disable-old-posts`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i'm not inclined to use those commands unless I can't get this to work.

Comment: I tried to implement custom mgmt commands. They worked when I ran them on the command line straight up. When added to the crontab, they failed.